# Bold points in Microsoft Chart control

Tags: asp.net, charts

I'm using microsoft Chart control in my web form. I want points(0, 0) should be bold on the chart. My code is as follows:

```
 DataTable dt = collection.ToDataTable();
        //   Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBind(collection, "Price", "OverallQuality", "Label=HotelName");

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            Chart1.Series.Add("series" + i);
            Chart1.Series["series" + i].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
         //   Chart1.Series["series" + i].Points.AddXY(double.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["Price"].ToString()), double.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["OverallQuality"].ToString()));
            Chart1.Series["series" + i].Points.AddXY(double.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["OverallQuality"].ToString()), double.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["Price"].ToString()));

            Chart1.Series["series" + i].MarkerSize = 10;
            Chart1.Series["series" + i].LegendText = dt.Rows[i]["HotelName"].ToString();
        }
     //   Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Price";
     //   Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Quality";
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Quality";
           Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Price";

        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 10;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = -10;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 10;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -10;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;

        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the PointWidth of the series?

```
Chart1.Series["series"]["PointWidth"] = "0.2";
```

You can find a bunch of examples of manipulating this property, such as t[his](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-set-change-chart-datapoint.html). But the trick, for your situation, is dealing with the fact that you can only manipulate this property for the entire series. [This](http://support2.dundas.com/forum/tm.aspx?m=10168&mpage=1&key=&#10168) post leads me to believe you will have problems setting it for just this particular point, unless you can separate is into it's own somehow. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137157/force-a-gap-between-points-on-the-x-axis-ms-net-chart-controls-column-chart) an exmample from stack somewhat similar that might help, depending on how your information is formatted.